# Travis CI - Android Build Script

Tags: android, travis-ci

I am tying to use Travis CI for Android build for the projects in GitHub. I have created the following .travis.yml file in GitHub and when the project build is triggered it gives build success.

The script is:

```
language: android
 jdk: oraclejdk8
  env:
    matrix:
      - ANDROID_TARGET=android-23 ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
  android:
    components:
      - build-tools-26.0.1
      - android-23
      - extra-android-m2repository
      - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-23
      - extra-android-support
      - extra-android-m2repository
    licenses:
      - 'android-sdk-license-.+'
 script:
 - chmod +x ./gradlew
```

But now when I put some error in the .java or .xml file to trigger another, build, the build goes through and it does not fail. Can you please let me know as to what changes to I need to make in the .travis.yml file.

**Update (10/18)**:

Based on the accepted answer and other SO posts the updated YML which worked is the following:

```
language: android
jdk: oraclejdk8
env:
  matrix:
    - ANDROID_TARGET=android-26 ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
android:
  components:
    - tools
    - platform-tools
    - tools
    - build-tools-26.0.1
    - android-26
    - extra-android-m2repository
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-26
    - extra-android-support
  licenses:
    - android-sdk-preview-license-52d11cd2
    - android-sdk-license-.+
    - google-gdk-license-.+
before_script:
- chmod +x ./gradlew
script:
- ./gradlew build
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script section does nothing but make the gradle script executable. You need to actually execute it too.

```
script:
 - chmod +x ./gradlew
 - ./gradlew
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added ./gradlew build and now it is working fine. The build is working properly. The updated travis yml is also posted in the original query